# Table equal column width when only multicolumn cells

Tags: tables, tabularx

I have to create a table containing some package header information. I created a HTML reference layout, I now want to *translate* it to LaTeX.

**HTML:**
[image]

**LaTeX:**

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,titlepage,openbib]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\setlength\tabcolsep{.5pt}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|*{16}{C|}}
\hline
  \multicolumn{4}{|r|}{4} 
& \multicolumn{4}{r|}{8} 
& \multicolumn{4}{r|}{12}
& \multicolumn{4}{r|}{16}\\
\hline
  \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{B/R}
& \multicolumn{5}{c|}{Msg-Type}
& \multicolumn{5}{c|}{Src-Addr}
& \multicolumn{5}{c|}{Dest-Addr}\\
\hline
  \multicolumn{16}{|c|}{Fletcher-16 Checksum}\\
\hline
  \multicolumn{8}{|c|}{Payload-Length in Bits}
& \multicolumn{8}{c|}{Payload max. 28 Byte}\\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

**Result:**
[image]

What am I missing?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LaTeX needs a bit more information in order to determine the cell widths correctly. In the following, this is achieved by providing explicit calculations for the *usable* widths of 7 of 8 cells in rows 1 and 2. The eighth cell -- the one that contains "B/R" -- is given its natural cell attribute, *not* `\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{B/R}`.

The calculations are based on the fact that if the *usable* width of a cell defined by

```
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\Centering}X|}
```

is, say, `Z`, then the *usable* width of a combination of 4 of these cells is given by `4Z + (4-1)*2*\tabcolsep + (4-1)*\arrayrulewidth`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\Centering}X}
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\RaggedLeft}X}

\setlength\tabcolsep{2pt} % '0.5pt' seems rather extreme

\begin{document}

\noindent % <-- important
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|*{16}{C|}}
\hline
\multicolumn{4}{|>{\hsize=\dimexpr4\hsize+6\tabcolsep+3\arrayrulewidth\relax}R|}{4}  & 
\multicolumn{4}{ >{\hsize=\dimexpr4\hsize+6\tabcolsep+3\arrayrulewidth\relax}R|}{8}  &
\multicolumn{4}{ >{\hsize=\dimexpr4\hsize+6\tabcolsep+3\arrayrulewidth\relax}R|}{12} &
\multicolumn{4}{ >{\hsize=\dimexpr4\hsize+6\tabcolsep+3\arrayrulewidth\relax}R|}{16} \\
\hline
B/R & 
\multicolumn{5}{ >{\hsize=\dimexpr5\hsize+8\tabcolsep+4\arrayrulewidth\relax}C|}{Msg-Type}  & \multicolumn{5}{ >{\hsize=\dimexpr5\hsize+8\tabcolsep+4\arrayrulewidth\relax}C|}{Src-Addr}  &
\multicolumn{5}{ >{\hsize=\dimexpr5\hsize+8\tabcolsep+4\arrayrulewidth\relax}C|}{Dest-Addr} \\
\hline
\multicolumn{16}{|c|}{Fletcher-16 Checksum} \\
\hline
\multicolumn{8}{|c|}{Payload-Length in Bits} & 
\multicolumn{8}{ c|}{Payload max.\ 28 Byte} \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Okay, thanks. Would this also work when I have no 'Z' because for example I expand the first cell to span 2 columns and shrink the second? Does this \dimexpr 'contain' 1/16 * the size I specified?

Comment: @Kaskorian - I'm not sure I understand the gist of your follow-up questions. If you're asking whether the specific approach I took in the answer shown above is guaranteed to work in circumstances that could be arbitrarily different from the setup you provided in your query, the only possible answer is a resounding "no". One has to, in essence, solve a constrained optimization problem in order to obtain the values of the widths of the cells that consist of combinations of 4 or 5 "basic" cells. *How* this constrained optimization problem gets solved in practice depends on the constraints.